# CUDA: synchronizing threads

Tags: optimization, cuda, synchronization

Almost anywhere I read about programming with CUDA there is a mention of the importance that all of the threads in a warp do the same thing.
In my code I have a situation where I can't avoid a certain condition. It looks like this:

```
// some math code, calculating d1, d2
if (d1 < 0.5)
{
    buffer[x1] += 1;  // buffer is in the global memory
}
if (d2 < 0.5)
{
    buffer[x2] += 1;
}
// some more math code.
```

Some of the threads might enter into one for the conditions, some might enter into both and other might not enter into either.

Now in order to make all the thread get back to "doing the same thing" again after the conditions, should I synchronize them after the conditions using  `__syncthreads()` ? Or does this somehow happens automagically?
Can two threads be *not* doing the same thing due to one of them being one operation behind, thus ruining it for everyone? Or is there some behind the scenes effort to get them to do the same thing again after a branch?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Within a warp, no threads will "get ahead" of any others.  If there is a conditional branch and it is taken by some threads in the warp but not others (a.k.a. warp "divergence"), the other threads will just idle until the branch is complete and they all "converge" back together on a common instruction.  So if you only need within-warp synchronization of threads, that happens "automagically."

But different warps are not synchronized this way.  So if your algorithm requires that certain operations be complete across many warps then you'll need to use explicit synchronization calls (see the CUDA Programming Guide, Section 5.4).

---

**EDIT:** reorganized the next few paragraphs to clarify some things.

There are really two different issues here: Instruction synchronization and memory visibility.

- `__syncthreads()`  enforces instruction synchronization and ensures memory visibility, but only within a block, not across blocks (CUDA Programming Guide, Appendix B.6).  It is useful for write-then-read on shared memory, but is not appropriate for synchronizing global memory access.
- `__threadfence()` ensures global memory visibility but doesn't do any instruction synchronization, so in my experience it is of limited use (but see sample code in Appendix B.5).
- Global instruction synchronization is not possible within a kernel.  If you need `f()` done on all threads before calling `g()` on any thread, split `f()` and `g()` into two different kernels and call them serially from the host.
- If you just need to increment shared or global counters, consider using the atomic increment function `atomicInc()` (Appendix B.10).  In the case of your code above, if `x1` and `x2` are not globally unique (across all threads in your grid), non-atomic increments will result in a race-condition, similar to the last paragraph of Appendix B.2.4.

Finally, keep in mind that any operations on global memory, and synchronization functions in particular (including atomics) are bad for performance.

Without knowing the problem you're solving it is hard to speculate, but perhaps you can redesign your algorithm to use shared memory instead of global memory in some places.  This will reduce the need for synchronization and give you a performance boost.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. So if the conditional branches do the same amount of work, this shouldn't affect the performance, since each thread won't be idle for too long. Am I right?

Comment: @omegatai I realize your comment is old, but others might want to know, so here goes: A warp can process only one instruction at a time, so if some of the threads in a warp do one thing and the rest of the threads do something else, the total time is the sum of the amounts of time for those two groups of threads. There is no time overlap within a warp. Performance is affected.

Answer (score 2):

From section 6.1 of the CUDA Best Practices Guide:

> Any flow control instruction (if, switch, do, for, while) can significantly affect
>   the instruction throughput by causing threads of the same warp to diverge; that is,
>   to follow different execution paths. If this happens, the different execution paths
>   must be serialized, increasing the total number of instructions executed for this
>   warp. When all the different execution paths have completed, the threads converge
>   back to the same execution path.

So, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no. You don't need to do anything special.
Anyway, you can fix this, instead of your code you can do something like this:

```
buffer[x1] += (d1 < 0.5);
buffer[x2] += (d2 < 0.5);
```

You should check if you can use shared memory and access global memory in a coalesced pattern. Also be sure that you DON'T want to write to the same index in more than 1 thread.

Comment: The trick is subtle but by doing this you are not branching at all!

Answer (score 2):

In Gabriel's response:

"Global instruction synchronization is not possible within a kernel. If you need f() done on all threads before calling g() on any thread, split f() and g() into two different kernels and call them serially from the host."

What if the reason you need f() and g() in same thread is because you're using register memory, and you want register or shared data from f to get to g? 
That is, for my problem, the whole reason for synchronizing across blocks is because data from f is needed in g - and breaking out to a kernel would require a large amount of additional global memory to transfer register data from f to g, which I'd like to avoid